# Where can we find Apple Technical White Papers?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra, mojave

I've been able to locate a few technical papers using Google, but they're mostly hosted by various (sometimes shady) websites. Is there an official repository of recent (High Sierra or Mojave) white papers available on the internet?

```
https://kryptera.se/assets/uploads/2014/10/WP_FileVault2.pdf
https://webobjects.cdw.com/webobjects/media/pdf/CDWCA/CA_Evaluating_And_Deploy_White_Paper.pdf
https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Publications/sp/800-179/rev-1/draft/documents/sp800-179r1-draft.pdf
http://m.softchoice.com/cms/brands/apple/pdf/OSX_Lion_ActiveDirectory.pdf
```

Comment: Did you try at apple.com and developer.apple.com?

Comment: Apple is not government - do they have to release them?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you clarify your query and specify exactly what technical white papers are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

## Developer Documentation

Apple publish their technical documentation, including occasional white papers, on the sub-domain [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com).

Apple currently promotes https://developer.apple.com/documentation as the official source of technical information about their products.

### Archive

The [archived documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/) contains many useful documents. These are marked as no longer being updated, but their contents are accurate at the date of publishing.

Of particular interest will be the [technical notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Technical%20Notes). These documents contain a wealth of information, such as the excellent [TN2083: Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794) and [TN2124 Mac OS X Debugging Magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2124/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003391).